# redux-saga select() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I can't get the redux-saga/effects select method to work as advertised.  I've tried many attempts, Here is an example of my simpliest attempt to use select, which I expect to return my state but instead returns undefined.

Saga.js:

```
export function* selectTest() {
  const temp = yield* select();
  console.log('select returns: ', temp);
  return temp;
}

export default [
  selectTest,
]
```

in routes.js (I'm using react-boilerplate)

```
return [
 {
    path,
    name: 'home',
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
      const importModules = Promise.all([
          System.import('containers/UiComponentsHomePage/sagas')
          System.import('containers/UiComponentsHomePage'),
      ]);

    const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

    importModules.then(([saga, component]) => {
      injectSagas(saga.default);
      renderRoute(component);
    });

    importModules.catch(errorLoading);
   },
  }
 ];
```

I would expect to see my state printed out after select returns, but instead it is returning undefined.  I can see my state is correctly set up and other components can use it.

Why isn't select() returning state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not use `yield *`, just use `yield select()`.
`yield *` is use for child generator integrate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an actual selector function.  The simplest example would be:

```
function* selectAndPrintState() {
    const selectAllState = (state) => state;

    const allState = yield select(selectAllState);
    console.log(allState);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work.  Select, without a selector function, is suppose to return the whole state.  I was trying that to debug why my selector wasn't called and it didn't work either, suggesting the issue is with select not being recognized at all.